Possible to register multiple windows services with the same executable based on feature selection?
Using Wix Toolset and only the standard features, is there a way to register the same executable multiple times as a Windows Service with different arguments, but each service registration is dependent on which features that are chosen in the installer?
Example:
<Component Id="8420977C981F453ABDFA72A3A34BDAD0" Guid="{A6262383-1763-4870-81D5-C67ABDD9DD10}">
    <File Id="8BCA8B8076ADE6BBF1CF6CF91FD2A9C2" KeyPath="yes"
        Source="Output\Release\MyServiceExecutable.exe" />
    <ServiceInstall
        Type="ownProcess"
        Account="LocalSystem"
        Arguments="Feature1"
        Name="Name of service 1"
        DisplayName="Display name of service 1"
        Description="Startup and monitoring of Feature1"
        Start="auto"
        Vital="yes"
        ErrorControl="normal"
        Interactive="no">
    </ServiceInstall>
    <ServiceControl Id="0AE8B11004B7443EA7FC4827EF299239" Name="Name of service 1"
        Remove="uninstall" Stop="install" />
    <!-- The following service only to be installed if feature 2 is selected as well. Note that is
    is the same executable, just a different argument. -->
    <ServiceInstall
        Type="ownProcess"
        Account="LocalSystem"
        Arguments="Feature2"
        Name="Name of service 2"
        DisplayName="Display name of service 2"
        Description="Startup and monitoring of Feature2"
        Start="auto"
        Vital="yes"
        ErrorControl="normal"
        Interactive="no">
    </ServiceInstall>
    <ServiceControl Id="8fb32b090d034356aa2ab9fb533d2176" Name="Name of service 2"
        Remove="uninstall" Stop="install" />
</Component>

It works fine to register the same executable this way for all services I need, but currently it's all or nothing.
I've looked into the condition function, which is not allowed within the ServiceInstall.
And I've seen some examples using preprocessor statements like <?if &feature=3 ?>, but I don't understand how a preprocessor statement would help me.

I'm not sure this can be done without a bootstrapper of some kind. Maybe a custom UI could populate the properties you need before the features get decided. Something like this about creating custom WiX UIs might be an option.
However, I had almost the exact same issue and I personally would recommend using burn to make a bootstrapper, it should be pretty quick to get off the ground. A super simple bundle UI can be used to select which features and options you would like your MSI to install. It can then pass these selections to the MSI through MsiProperties.
<MsiPackage 
    Id="MyMSI" 
    Compressed="yes" 
    EnableFeatureSelection="yes" 
    SourceFile="$(targetPathToYourMsiOutput)">
    <MsiProperty Name="OPTION1" Value="[Option1]" />
    <MsiProperty Name="OPTION2" Value="[Option2]" />
</MsiPackage>

Then you can parse these into their own MSI features where you control the feature level as follows:
    <Feature Id="Service1" Title="Service1.MSI" Level="0">
        <Level Value="1" Condition="OPTION1=1" />
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="WhateverComponentGroupStartsThisService" />
    </Feature>

    <Feature Id="Service2" Title="Service2.MSI" Level="0">
        <Level Value="1" Condition="OPTION2=1" />
        <ComponentGroupRef Id="WhateverComponentGroupStartsThisOtherService" />
    </Feature>


One challenge with this is that the  has to be a part of the same  as the file you are registering, so I do not think this would help. Since I still would have to have all the ServiceInstall's within the same component, and  is at component level, it would not help me.
I think a more viable option would be to create a Custom Action to do this, which I was hoping to avoid. Most comments here also says to avoid installing services through custom actions.

@gulgummiand I see, there might still be other ways but worst case you could defer the service startup to a custom action. Pass through the service selection variables to the custom actions and then just use the Windows sc.exe to create them however you want.
I've started multiple services this way and it works great. It's a bit of a pain but will have all the configurability you need as far as I can tell.
